# Peak finder in Python in O(log n) complexity

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python, thus the question. I'm trying to solve a standard interview question, which is finding a peak in an array. A peak is defined as a number which is greater than it's left and right neighbor. I'm trying to find the largest such peak.

This is my code:

```
def main():
    arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
    print(find_peak(arr))


def find_peak(arr):
    return _find_peak(arr, 0, len(arr))


def _find_peak(arr, start, stop):

    mid = (start + stop) // 2

    if arr[mid] > arr[mid - 1] and arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]:
        return arr[mid]

    elif arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]:
        _find_peak(arr, 0, mid - 1)

    elif arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]:
        _find_peak(arr, mid + 1, stop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of this program is `None`, where as the expected output is `24`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't return any values from _find_peak, so the result will always be None.

Comment: *Largest* peak? Not possible. Even if you just want to find *any* peak, you can't do it in O(log n) with this definition of "peak"; it's only possible for a definition where a peak is any element *at least* as great as its neighbors, rather than *greater*.

Comment: Apologies, amended that wrong line. It slipped through the crack.

Comment: You should `return _find_peak...` in the `elif` parts.. But you'll still get bad result (at least not `None`) :)

Comment: I wonder whether you're looking for this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/29a970409f7bebf1ad9b

Comment: Ah my mistake, peak not peek...

Comment: If you figure out a log n solution please share it.

Comment: There's a log(n) solution if you assume the first and last elements in the array are the two smallest elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61983789/find-a-sequence-in-an-unsorted-list/61984402#61984402

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Data

```
arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
```

### A one-liner:

One line should be enough:

```
max_peak = max(x2 for x1, x2, x3 in zip(arr, arr[1:], arr[2:]) if x1 < x2 > x3)
```

### In a loop

Maybe easier to understand when you are new to Python:

```
peak = float('-inf')
for x1, x2, x3 in zip(arr, arr[1:], arr[2:]):
    if x1 < x2 > x3:
        peak = max(peak, x2)
print(peak)
```

Output:

```
24
```

### All peaks

You can also use a one-liner to get all peaks:

```
>>> [x2 for x1, x2, x3 in zip(arr, arr[1:], arr[2:]) if x1 < x2 > x3]
[13, 24]
```

and get the greatest one with `max()` on the result.

### Explanation

Let's have a look at some of the components of the solution. I am working with Python 3 here, as everybody should. ;)

You can slice lists.

```
>>> arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
```

This gives you all of the list but the first element:

```
>>> arr[1:]
[12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
```

Here its starts with element three:

```
>>> arr[2:]
[13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
```

The [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) function zips multiple sequences together. To visualize what happens, you can convert the zip object into a list:

```
>>> list(zip(arr, arr[1:], arr[2:]))
[(7, 12, 13),
 (12, 13, 8),
 (13, 8, 2),
 (8, 2, 16),
 (2, 16, 24),
 (16, 24, 11),
 (24, 11, 5),
 (11, 5, 1)]
```

Python supports tuple unpacking. This allows to assign individual names to all members of a tuple:

```
>>> x1, x2, x3 = (7, 12, 13)
>>> x1
7
>>> x2
12
>>> x3
13
```

Another nice feature is the comparison of more than two objects:

```
>>> 10 < 12 > 8
True
```

This is equivalent to:

```
>>> (10 < 12) and (12 > 8)
True
```

Python offers [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [x * 2 for x in range(2, 6)]
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

[Generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) work in a similar way but don't produce a list but an iterator and can be consumed without using lots of memory:

```
>>> sum(x * 2 for x in range(2, 6))
28
```

Comment: Can you explain the code a bit. This is going way above me.

Comment: Added a bit of explanation. Covering all this in detail with examples and exercises  can be easily one day of teaching. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a return statement for your two `elif` cases

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11079356)

Comment: @Prune, this answers the question. It may not be a high quality answer, but it does provide an answer. Please be more careful when reviewing. Ensure that it actually is *not* an answer before making it as such.

Comment: From the SO guidelines I've seen, you should provide correct return statements to fully qualify as a valid answer.  That's my interpretation (including answers *I* have left a little short), hardly canonized SO practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 13 also is a peak (greater than 12 and 8).

Try this approach:

```
def main():
    arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
    print(find_peaks(arr))


def find_peaks(arr):
    return list(_search(arr))


def _search(arr):
    last = len(arr) - 1
    for i, e in enumerate(arr):
        if not any((i > 0 and arr[i-1] > e, i < last and arr[i+1] > e)):
            yield e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you don’t understand anything, ask!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach – using only one function:

```
def main():
    arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
    print(find_peaks(arr))


def find_peaks(arr):
    last = len(arr) - 1
    return [
        e for i, e in enumerate(arr)
        if not any((i > 0 and arr[i-1] > e, i < last and arr[i+1] > e))
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would really help if you could explain your approach. I'm a stark newbie in python.

Comment: The `[... for ...]` syntax is a list comprehension: it builds a list of elements for each iteration over the iterable after `in`. The `enumerate()` function returns a iterable of which each element is a tuple containing the index of an element (`i`) of the `arr` and the element itself (`e`). The `if` inside the list comprehesion filters the elements: `any()` returns `True` if any element of the parameter is true, so it checks if the current element is greater than the left (`arr[i-1]`) and right (`arr[i+i]`) neighbours (nor left or right one is greater).

Comment: In other words: I just filter the original `arr`, selecting only the elements that’s not less than left neighbour, nor less than right one (`if not any(…)`).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can find a peak in O(log N) time, because by definition the items cannot be in order, and there is no way to predict the peaky-ness of any item in a list given other items, except that comparing item N with item N+1 is presumably reflexive - it tells you that either N or N+1 might be a peak. That gets you to N/2 compares, which must then be followed by N/2 more compares to check the other side of the peak.

Here's a `local_maxima(iterable)` function that you can use with `max()` to find peaks. It treats start/end elements as peaks if they are greater than their one neighbor.

```
data = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1, None, 2, None, 3, 4, None, 5, 1, None]
firstpeak = [12, 7, 9, 8]
lastpeak = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def local_maxima(it):
    """Find local maxima in iterable _it_. Compares with None using
    `is (not) None`, and using operator `<`."""

    peaking = False
    last = None

    for item in it:

        # Deal with last item peaking
        if peaking and (item is None or item < last):
            yield last
            peaking = False
        elif item is None:
            peaking = False
        elif last is None or last < item:
            peaking = True
        else:
            peaking = False

        last = item

    if peaking:
        yield last

print([x for x in local_maxima(data)])
print("Highest:", max(local_maxima(data)))
print([x for x in local_maxima(firstpeak)])
print("Highest:", max(local_maxima(firstpeak)))
print([x for x in local_maxima(lastpeak)])
print("Highest:", max(local_maxima(lastpeak)))
```