# Find a sequence in an unsorted list

Tags: algorithm

So, I am given an unsorted list A = (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>) with n distinct elements. My goal here is to find the middle index i (1 <= i <= n) of a sequence where a<sub>i-1</sub> < a<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>i</sub> > a<sub>i+1</sub>. The algorithm should run in O(log(n)) worst case. It is also given that a<sub>0</sub> = a<sub>n+1</sub> = -inf.

So basically i need to find an index surrounded by smaller number than itself, such as {1,5,3}, where 1 and 3 are smaller than 5.

Example:

Input: A = {1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6}

Output: 4 (because of the sequence {4, 5, 3})

This algorithm would be extremly easy if the worst case was to be O(n), where a simple for-loop could check that sequence, but I'm having a hard time with the fact that it needs to run worst case O(log(n)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Peak finder in Python in O(log n) complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095198/peak-finder-in-python-in-olog-n-complexity)

Comment: Yes! That's pretty much my problem, but the answer does not specefy that the algorithm runs in O(log n) time. Another thing is that I do not know what the zip function does in python.

Comment: Yes, I'll retract my close vote. I think I know how to solve the problem, and I'll answer here.

Comment: What if there exist more (than one) peaks?

Comment: I am required to return a single index, meaning a single peak, so I'm guessing it's up to me to chose which one I want to return.

Comment: This question looks to be leetcode 162

Comment: It sure does looks to be leetcode 162. Haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that if you have three elements `a_i`, `a_j`, `a_k` with `i<j<k` and `a_j > a_i` and `a_j > a_k`, then there must be a peak between `i` and `k`. The proof is easy: the maximum value that lies between `a_i` and `a_k` must be a peak, and it can't be either of the endpoints.

You can use this observation to solve the problem in logarithmic time.

We'll keep three values: `x, y, z` such that `x<y<z` and `a_y > a_x` and `a_y > a_z`. At the start, initialize `x`, `y`, `z` to `0, (n+1)/2, n+1`. (The conditions will hold, because `a_0 = a_(n+1) = -inf`).

Now consider the triples `(x, (x+y)/2, y)`, `((x+y)/2, y, (y+z)/2)`, `(y, (y+z)/2, z))`. One of these triples can serve as our next `(x, y, z)`. (The proof is easy, but I'll leave it to you).

This process halves the range searched each time, and we stop when we're down to a small interval (say `z-x < 5`), at which point the peak is at most 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: I see. So basically we are going to use the x, y and z to sort of divide and conquer, where x, y and z are going to behave as left, right and mid pointers. Am I thinking right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The only surprise is that usually in divide and conquer we go to the left or the right of the midpoint, but in this algorithm we can also take the middle third.

Comment: I think I got the hang of it. Thank you so much! I'll mark your answer.